# prove a divisibility based on modulus condition

Tags: elementary-number-theory, modular-arithmetic, divisibility

Prove that:
$$8|(p-1)(q-1)$$ iff at least one $p,q ≡ 1 mod 4$

This was a single part in a problem but I'm not really sure what theorem to use to figure this out. Any ideas?

EDIT:
forgot to mention $p, q$ are both odd primes

Comment: Honestly it seems kind of trivial/obvious because 4 divides 8 and if 8 divides something, the something would have to be divided by 4 and since you're taking p-1 or q-1, there would have to be a remainder of 1. Just not sure how to write that in mathematical words

Comment: $p = 5$ and $q = 2$ gives $(5-1)(2-1) = 4 \cdot 1 = 4$, but $8$ does not divide $4$?

Comment: @greenteam as Dair said, assuming $p,q \ge 0$ at least you have one of them, for instance $p$, in the shape of $p=1+4k$ for some $k \ge 0$, so $(p-1)(q-1)=4k(q-1)$, so if $k=1$ and $q=2$ for instance it is not true... $8 \not \mid 4$imho, the conditions of the problem should be different.

Comment: @Dair
That is correct, sorry I thought one thing and wrote another. thanks!

Comment: @iadvd yeah I thought it was a little confusing

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Let $4 \nmid (p-1) = 4a+b$, $4 \nmid (q-1) = 4c+d$, where $0 < b,d < 4$, and let $(p-1)(q-1) = 8k$.

Then, $$(4a+b)(4c+d) = 8k \implies 4(4ac + bc+ad) + bd = 8k \implies bd = 4(2k-(4ac+bc+ad))$$

Now, two cases arise:

1)If $b \neq 2$ or $d \neq 2$, then the right side is divisible by $4$, while the left side is not, this is a contradiction.

2) If $b=d=2$, then on simplifying, we get $1 = 2k-4ac-2c+2a$, which is a contradiction as the left side is odd while the right side is even.

Hence, $4|(p-1)$ or $4|(q-1)$. This part is clear.

The other way is not true unless you assume that $p$ and $q$ are odd.

For example, if we let $p=5$,$q=6$ then $8 \nmid 20$, although $4 | (5-1)$.

However, suppose that $p$ and $q$ are odd. Then, $(p-1)$ and $(q-1)$ are certainly multiples of $2$. If in addition one of them is a multiple of four, then their product is a multiple of $4 \times 2 = 8$.

Hence, the other way follows when $p$ and $q$ are both odd. Otherwise, it does not follow.